# How to display real time updates to an image in Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, bitmap

I am trying to create an application that generates a bitmap image every frame based on user actions and have it display that image to the screen. I would like the application to also be able to update that image in unity in real time as soon as the user makes another action.

I have created an application that does this and it works. However, it is veryyyy slow. My Update() method is attached below.

My idea was:

- Capture user data (mouse location).
- Convert that data into a special signal format that another program recognizes.
- Have that program return a bitmap image.
- Use that bitmap as a texture and update the existing texture with the new image.

Code:

```
UnityEngine.Texture2D oneTexture;
Bitmap currentBitmap;
private int frameCount = 0;



void Update()
{ 
    // Show mouse position in unity environment 
    double xValue = Input.mousePosition.x;
    double yValue = Screen.height - Input.mousePosition.y;  
    myPoints = "" + xValue + "," + yValue + Environment.NewLine;

    // Show heatmap being recorded.
    signals = Program.ConvertStringToSignalsList(myPoints);  
    currentBitmap = Program.CreateMouseHeatmap(Screen.width, Screen.height, signals);

    // Update old heatmap texture. 
    UpdateTextureFromBitmap();
    ri.texture = oneTexture;
    ri.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height);
    frameCount++;

    // Write points to Database.
    StartCoroutine(WriteToDB(xValue, yValue));  // <<<<< Comment out when playback.
}






private void UpdateTextureFromBitmap()
{
    // Convert Bitmap object into byte array instead of creating actual 
    // .bmp image file each frame.
    byte[] imageBytes = ImageToBytes(currentBitmap);
    BMPLoader loader = new BMPLoader();
    BMPImage img = loader.LoadBMP(imageBytes);

    // Only initialize the Texture once.
    if (frameCount == 0)
    { 
        oneTexture = img.ToTexture2D();
    }
    else
    {
        Color32[] imageData = img.imageData;
        oneTexture.SetPixels32(imageData);
        oneTexture.Apply();
    }
}
```

I was wondering if someone could help me improve the rate at which the image updates to the screen? I know that it is possible to make this program much faster but I am so new to unity and C# that I don't know how to make that happen. Also if there is a completely different way that I should be going about doing this then I am open to that too. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Also, below is a screenshot of the Profiler showing the breakdown of CPU Usage. Currently it looks like every frame is taking about 500ms.

[image: Program performance from profiler]

Comment: If you examine this `Update` call in the profiler, how is the runtime divided among its contents? .

Comment: You're creating a new texture every frame. Don't do that. Reuse the one you already have.

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite an image every frame? That is extremely costly along with calling network!/db actions every frame (and not necessary).

Comment: Hi @Immorality, I am trying to create a 2D heatmap application that shows mouse movement history on the screen. Rewriting a image every frame is the only way that I know how to make that happen. I am very new to Unity and don't know what a better solution be. 

Also, I was thinking about calling the network/db write method just once at the very end of the program instead of in the update method. But writing to the db is super quick so that's not the main problem.

Comment: Hi @Draco18s, thank you for your feedback. I am not sure how I would go about doing that. Would you be able to provide a simple example please?

Comment: Hi @Ruzihm thank you for your feedback. After analyzing the code and debugging it I've found that this line:

 "currentBitmap = Program.CreateMouseHeatmap(Screen.width, Screen.height, signals);" takes the most time.

Comment: Yes, it is, because *`You're creating a new texture every frame. Don't do that. Reuse the one you already have.`* And you can do that by not calling `Create` every frame and using the Graphics API to blit the new data onto the existing texture. As you haven't included the contents of `Program.CreateMouseHeatmap` I can't suggest alterations.

Comment: Hi @Draco18s, I have updated my code using your suggestion of only creating a single texture object and updating it's pixel data every frame instead of creating new texture objects. After making those changes unfortunately I am not seeing any significant performance improvements. 

I have added my UpdateTextureFromBitmap() method in the code above so that you can see what it does.

Comment: @Ruzihm, I updated my question above to show a screenshot of what I am seeing from the profiler.

Comment: @user3665751 how long does it take for `Program.CreateMouseHeatmap` to execute? If you want to run the application at 60 frames per second, you have less than 17 ms to spend on executing calls per frame. If `Program.CreateMouseHeatmap` takes longer than `10ms` you should consider not calling it in `Update` in a way that waits for it to complete execution before `Update` completes.

Comment: @Ruzihm  I think you are on the right track. My Program.CreateMouseHeatmap() takes about 200ms to execute. This method basically accepts a list of x,y coordinates and generates a Bitmap file that has the heatmap of those x,y coordinates. The file that it creates is relative to the screensize of the computer that is running the program. So sometimes the image that it generates can be 4000x2100 in resolution. I don't know how else to make that method take less time.

Comment: @user3665751 Yes, that is definitely the cause of the slowdown. You might consider using Unity's [Job System](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Jobs.IJob.html) to call `Program.CreateMouseHeatmap` and store the results in some variable in parallel with the main thread. Then, the main thread can update the screen with whatever is the most recent information in the variable every frame.  That way, it won't slow down the main thread/the framerate. You may want to avoid starting one of these jobs every frame, and instead only starting one when the last one is completed.

Comment: @Ruzihm Okay, thank you for your advice. I will give that a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I was not sure if the processing on the heatmap would be a significant contributor. Btw, `UpdateTextureFromBitmap(Bitmap actualBitmap)` that parameter goes unused. You then proceed to convert `currentBitmap` into bytes, then back into a bitmap with `loader.LoadBMP(imageBytes)`.

Comment: @Draco18s Good catch, I forgot to remove the parameter actualBitmap from when I had the method accept a Bitmap as  an argument. I actually have a class variable called currentBitmap set at the top of the class which is the one that gets updated every frame. I've updated the code above to correctly represent my current script.

Comment: You forgot this bit too: `UpdateTextureFromBitmap(currentBitmap);` ;)